# Finding conditions on unspecified CDF that permit a solution to an equation

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

[A duplicate thread can also be found at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131142/finding-conditions-on-unspecified-cdf-that-permit-a-solution-to-an-equation ]

Let $F(\alpha) := \mathbb{P}(\tilde{\alpha} \le \alpha)$ be an arbitrary, strictly increasing and twice differentiable CDF that is defined on the interval $[0, \overline{\alpha}]$, where $\overline{\alpha}>1$ may be infinite. Moreover, let $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{\alpha}) = 1$.

Let $N \ge 2$ be a natural number, and $\delta \in (0,1)$ real.

I am looking for necessary and sufficient criteria on $F$ in order to find a solution to

$(N-1)[1-\delta+\delta F(\alpha)] - \delta \alpha F'(\alpha) =0$,

where $\alpha$ can be any real positive number not larger than $\overline{\alpha}$.

Now, it is clear that the left term, $(N-1)[1-\delta+\delta F(\alpha)]$, is strictly increasing in $\alpha$ and bounded above by $N-1$. Hence, if the probability mass is sufficiently "concentrated" in some interval (implying that $F'(.)$ is large in that interval), a solution $\alpha^*$ must exist by continuity of $F'$ and $F$.

However, it would be nice to have some sharper conditions on $F$ that are necessary or sufficient for a solution. Ideally, I'd wish to have a result that gives an upper bound on $F$'s variance, or similar.

One thing that seems problematic is that the above equation never uses the fact that $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{\alpha})=1$. I've tried to apply Markov's inequality but it didn't help me much.

Numerical simulations reveal that a solution can usually be found if the variance of the considered CDF is sufficiently low. Examples include $F$ log-normal or $F(\alpha) = \left(\dfrac{b\, \alpha}{b+1}\right)^{\displaystyle b}$ for $b>1$. The uniform distribution on $[0,2]$ is a borderline case that doesn't permit a solution.

I would greatly appreciate any help or ideas to this (economics) research problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions on $F$ are

1. $F(0)=0$
2. $F(\overline{\alpha}) = 1$
3. $F'(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in (0, \overline{\alpha})$
4. $\int_0^{\overline{\alpha}} x F'(x) dx = 1$.
5. $F'$ is differentiable.

These are all *nonlocal* in the sense that sufficiently small (smooth) perturbations of $F$ within small neighborhoods of any finite discrete set of points in $(0, \overline{\alpha})$ can be found which preserve them all. By applying such a local perturbation we can modify $F'$ within a narrow interval to be as large as we want without changing any of the conditions.

The figures below may help in following this argument.

I claim there exists at least one $x_0 \in (0, \overline{\alpha})$ for which $(N-1)(1-\delta+\delta F(x_0)) - \delta x_0 F'(x_0) \gt 0$.  For if not, a simple comparison shows that $F(0)$ must be less than the value at $0$ of the (unique) solution to the first-order ordinary differential equation for $F$,

$$L[F](x) = (N-1)(1-\delta+\delta F(x)) - \delta x F'(x) = 0, \quad F(\overline{\alpha}) = 1.$$

This equation can explicitly be solved and its value at $0$ found to equal $1 - 1/\delta \lt 0$, whence $F(0) \lt 0$, violating the first condition.

Let's perturb $F$ to $\widehat{F}$. The following argument needs only routine constructions to be made rigorous: mix in tiny amounts of a distribution supported in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $x_0$ and another distribution supported in a neighborhood of an $x_1$ on the other side of $1$ from $x_0$ in such a way that the expectation of $F$ remains unchanged. By making the first of these mixed-in distributions have sufficiently small support, we can cause it to increase $F'$ at $x_0$ by any desired amount while changing $F(x_0)$ arbitrarily little. In this fashion we can cause $L[\widehat{F}](x_0)$ to range from $L[F](x_0)$ down to $-\infty$ in a continuous manner.  Do this so that $L[\widehat{F}](x_0) = 0$.

Therefore, there exist *no* restrictions whatsoever on any of the moments of $F$.  That explains why you had such difficulty obtaining any!

[image: Figures]

In these figures, the plots associated with the original $F$ are shown in blue and those associated with the perturbed CDF $\widehat{F}$ are shown in red.  As $\varepsilon$ shrinks, the two spikes in the PDF and $L[F]$ grow longer (vertically).  Here, I noticed that $L[F](3/2) \gt 0$, and so perturbed $F$ near $3/2$ and near a counterbalancing value $x_1 = 1/2$.  This creates two tiny *apparent* jumps around $3/2$ and $1/2$ in $F$, but upon closer inspection they are smooth--just steep.  Their steepness makes $L[F]$ small.  Because the jumps can be made arbitrarily steep, the spikes in $L[F]$ can be extended below zero, creating a zero-crossing: that solves the problem.  (Just for fun I have used an $F$ that fails to be twice differentiable at $0$: $F'$ diverges there.  The construction still goes through.)

The point is that we can *always* create such spikes (and give them arbitrarily small area, thereby changing $F$ by arbitrarily small amounts), so to obtain a zero-crossing it's enough to show that $L[F]$ must have some neighborhood in which it is positive. But if it is not, $F$ will fail to be a CDF: consistently negative values of $L[F]$ mean that $F'$ is too large, on average, and so if $F$ ends up with a limiting value of $1$ at the right--as it must in order to be a CDF--also it *must* have a negative value at $0$, which is not allowable.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reply! I was suspecting something along those lines, although it's a bit hard for me to evaluate all the steps of your argument. In particular, it is not completely intuitive to me why "[...] making the first of these mixed-in distributions have sufficiently small support, we can cause it to increase F′ at x0 by any desired amount while changing F(x0) arbitrarily little" preserves the variance of F, or any other higher moments. I must admit though that I have a relatively limited understanding of the technical details involved.

Comment: Moreover, while I can easily be convinced that no conditions on any moments of F can be given, both necessary and sufficient conditions on "other" peculiarities of F can be stated. I think it should usually (always?) hold that $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0}\alpha F'(\alpha) = 0$. Hence, in your terminology, $L[F](0) = (N-1)(1-\delta) > 0$. A necessary condition for a solution is thus that $(N-1)[1-\delta + \delta F(\alpha)] - \delta \alpha F'(\alpha) < 0$ for some $\alpha > 0$. Hence, at the very least, some $\alpha$ must exist such that $(N-1)(1-\delta) - \delta \alpha F'(\alpha) < 0$.

Comment: That is, some $\alpha > 0$ must exist such that $\alpha F'(\alpha) > (N-1)\frac{1-\delta}{\delta}$. In a very similar fashion, a sufficient condition for the existence of a solution is that $\alpha F'(\alpha) > \frac{N-1}{\delta}$ for some $\alpha > 0$. However, I'm wondering whether sharper conditions can be found.

Comment: You are right :  if $F$ is twice -    differentiable on $[ 0, \overline {\alpha}] $, then necessarily $F' $ is defined *and 
continuous* in a neighborhood of $0$, whence $F' $ is bounded at zero and the limit of $xF' (x) $ as $x\to 0 $ must be $0$ anyway.  But don't hope for sharper conditions.  I trust that the figures might help you gain some intuition concerning how little can be said about $F$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continued effort! The graphs are amazing and add lots of intution. I believe that I now understand your point pretty well -- in essence, we cannot give any meaningful conditions on $F$ whatsoever because an epsilon perturbation of the pdf can preserve all of the required properties (while letting $F$ almost unchanged), yet we can make the pdf as large as we want in order to guarantee a solution. I think it's interesting however that a solution fails to exist for such common distributions as uniform on $[0,2]$, or exponential with mean $1$.

Comment: Also, while we cannot give any conditions on $F$, my above argument shows that we can very well do so for $F'$. In particular, the "value adjusted density" ($\alpha F'(\alpha)$) has to be sufficiently large relative to the parameters $N$ and $\delta$. I wonder whether much more could be said if I imposed some regularity conditions on $F'$, like single-peakedness.

Comment: I have no problem finding solutions by perturbing the uniform and exponential cases. As you have begun to see, conditions on $F'$ are of a wholly different nature than conditions on $F$ and have little to do with conditions involving moments of the distribution.